# In vscode how do I write an expression to watch a property value of an object while debugging?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, extendscript

"ThisItem" is an object I want to watch. Is there some way to watch its property values? I can't find documentation on what sort of expression is used in the Watch panel.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try getting rid of `local` at the start of the variable name in the watch expression?

Comment: I tried that but that fails to get anything. The "local" part was generated by adding the object to the watch window. It returns NaN which seems to point to the object while anything else is undefined.

Comment: I didn't take Solomon Ucko's suggestion all the way ... it was actually everything at the beginning of the expression. 

    0/$.local

I had clicked add from the variables panel which placed that expression. Simply typing this, worked:

    ThisItem.clipping

I'm still unclear on what kinds of expressions the watch panel uses.